# How to use date range type parameter as normal java.util.date in jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created two input controllers BeginDate and EndDate as date range type. I need to convert that dates which are input as date range to util.date.These are data types I have created.

```
<parameter name="BeginDate" class="net.sf.jasperreports.types.date.DateRange"/>
<parameter name="EndDate" class="net.sf.jasperreports.types.date.DateRange"/>

  <![CDATA[SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE $X{BETWEEN,date,BeginDate,EndDate}
    AND total > 0;]]>
```

I need to use that dates in below.

```
   <![CDATA[SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    WHERE 
date >= $P{BeginDate} AND
date < $P{EndDate}
        AND total > 0;]]>
```

Comment: DateRange only holds a range, e.g. `5 DAYS` or `-1 WEEK`. If you want to select between actual calendar days/times, you should use the `Date` class.

Comment: A bit dated of a response, but the only reason why I'd think one would want to use the DateRange type is to allow for scheduling of reports, as with the current Jasper version one wont get the correct output if they schedule a report with a date parameter but will with a "DAY-1" parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateRange` type provides 2 methods: `getStart()` and `getEnd()` to get the beginning and end of the range. These methods return `java.util.Date` objects which you could use further.

But because the `DateRange` type is not allowed in the query expression you need to create new parameters of type `java.util.Date` to use as you want:

```
<parameter name="BeginDate_start" class="java.util.Date">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{BeginDate}.getStart()]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="EndDate_end" class="java.util.Date">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{EndDate}.getEnd()]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Then your query may look like so:

```
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE date >= $P{BeginDate_start} AND date < $P{EndDate_end} AND total > 0]]>
</queryString>
```