# Jasper Reports dynamic scheduled Date Time range parameters

Tags: jasper-reports

We are encountering issues with Jasper Reports parameters - specifically, date & time where we have scheduled reports to query the data for some specific date range e.g. `MONTH-3` until `DAY-1`. We originally figured `net.sf.jasperreports.types.date.DateRange` parameter type is exactly what we need - especially since logs shows both paramaters with respective time (23:59:59 and 00:00:00) but in reality the resulting SQL query does not include time - only the date.

It seems that `net.sf.jasperreports.types.date.DateRange` is the only type which supports dynamic values like `DAY`, `WEEK`, `MONTH` etc.

We already found some workarounds like [How to use date range type parameter as normal java.util.date in jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37207818/how-to-use-date-range-type-parameter-as-normal-java-util-date-in-jasper) where instead of 2x parameters there are 4x :) That does not look like a proper way but rather a hack.

According to documentation, `$X{BETWEEN, timestamp_column, DATE_RANGE_FROM, DATE_RANGE_TO}` is the way to go but doing so we are missing the time so the report is wrong unless we use some stupid approach like `DAY-2` and `DAY` but then again - specifying some exact dates leads to different results anyways.

So the question: how one is supposed to get a scheduled report for some date & time range (e.g. last 3 month or last 2 days or any custom range when running the report with exact values starting (00:00:00) given start date and ending (23:59:59) given end date) every day?

The resulting SQL would need to be something like this: `... (AND timestamp_column >= "2022-01-22 00:00:00" AND timestamp_column <= "2022-01-22 23:59:59"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$X{[BETWEEN], timestamp_column, DATE_RANGE_FROM, DATE_RANGE_TO}` (mind the square brackets at BETWEEN) to produce inclusive date range query clauses.

See [the sample documentation](https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/index.html) for more details.